# Combing degrees and minutes data columns, accounting for rolling over to next degree. (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a have a weird format for some data that I'm stuck working with.  it's a csv file that includes a timestamp column, a latitude minutes column which is a float, and longitude minutes column (float).  The data does include a starting Latitude and Longitude in degrees as well, but only a starting value.  I need to combine the latitude and longitude minutes columns with the starting values and convert to degrees and decimal degrees. I'm stuck with this format.

```
lat = 45
long = 75

data = {
    'time': [
        '2024-03-27 12:00:00', '2024-03-27 12:00:01', '2024- 03-27 12:00:02', '2024-03-27 12:00:03', '2024-03-27 12:00:04', '2024-03-27 12:00:05'
    ],
    'lat_minutes': [
        59.9955, 59.9963, 0.0180, 0.0230, 0.0050, 59.6500
    ],
    'long_minutes': [
        59.0250, 59.0750, 0.0020, 0.1850, 0.0750, 59.075
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    time                 lat_minutes       long_minutes
0   2024-03-27 12:00:00  59.9955            59.025
1   2024-03-27 12:00:01  59.9963            59.075
2   2024-03-27 12:00:02  0.0180             0.002
3   2024-03-27 12:00:03  0.0230             0.185
4   2024-03-27 12:00:04  0.0050             0.075
5   2024-03-27 12:00:05  59.6500            59.075
```

I need the output to make a new column with degrees.decimal format based on adding the minutes column to starting lat and long values accounting for adding a whole degree once teh minutes roll past 60, and subtracting a degree if they are decreasing and pass o going to 59.9999.

output should be this:

```
    time                 lat_minutes  long_minutes   Latitude  Longitude
0   2024-03-27 12:00:00  59.9955         59.025     45.999925   75.98375      
1   2024-03-27 12:00:01  59.9963         59.075     45.9999383  75.984583
2   2024-03-27 12:00:02  0.0180          0.002      46.00030    76.0003
3   2024-03-27 12:00:03  0.0230          0.185      46.00383    76.00308 
4   2024-03-27 12:00:04  0.0050          0.075      46.00125    76.00125
5   2024-03-27 12:00:05  59.6500         59.075     45.99416    75.98458
```

Comment: [How to make good reproducible Pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/235698).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome. As Mark suggested above, please condense your post into input dataframe sample / corresponding expected output. Skip what you say you know how to do, and jump straight to your problem. Please clarify "starting (staring) value".

Comment: In row 3, 4, & 5 of your expected output, the expected result is incorrect for example, adding 0.018 mins to 45 results in 45.0003 degrees not 46.0003 degrees. Is this a typo or are we missing a key aspect of the problem?

Comment: @itprorh66 The op was trying to describe that we need to infer that the 3rd row's 0.0180 minutes is actually 60.0180 minutes. This is because the data doesn't record the degree component of the offset. So, as the preceding value was 59.9963 minutes, we infer that the offset increased by 0.0217 minutes, rather than decreased by 59.9783 minutes.

Comment: @itprorh66 is correct in that the data doesn't record the degree component and the shift from 59.9963 to 0.0180 actually represents the geographic position moving from latitude 45.9999N to latitude 46.0003N.  Not the best data format, but what I'm stuck with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can be shortened, but this works (repeat the code for longitude)

```py
# calculate how much the minutes changed since the preceding row
delta = df['lat_minutes'] - df['lat_minutes'].shift(1)

# initialise the new degrees column to all zeros
df['lat'] = 0

# if minutes decreases by more than 30
# treat it as having moved forward over a degree boundary
# => record a +1 degree offset at that row
df.loc[delta < -30, 'lat'] += 1

# if minutes increases by more than 30
# treat it as having moved backward over a degree boundary
# => record a -1 degree offset at that row
df.loc[delta >  30, 'lat'] -= 1

# final degrees = cumulative sum of above 'offsets', plus base offset, plus minutes/60
df['lat'] = df['lat'].cumsum() + lat + df['lat_minutes'] / 60
```

Demo : https://www.online-python.com/rKvMuwq2sC

***Edit:*** Maybe a little cleaner...

```
delta = df['lat_minutes'] - df['lat_minutes'].shift(1)

offset = (
  (delta < -30).astype(int)
  -
  (delta >  30).astype(int)
)

df['lat'] = offset.cumsum() + lat + df['lat_minutes'] / 60
```

Final demo : https://www.online-python.com/7hdsye2VHE

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works great, and I think I even understand why.  I was trying a similar process using a mask.  i.e mask = df['lat_minutes']>df['lat_minutes'].shift() to identify the break points then I got lost....

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming, you are looking for something like the following:

```
def formDegrees(degree:float, offset: float) -> float:
    # create a decinmal degree value from datum  + offset
    if int(degree) == degree and offset < 60.0:
        # The simple case 
        return degree + offset/60
    deg_frac = (degree -int(degree))*60
    deg_frac += offset
    return int(degree) + deg_frac/60
```

Using this function given the following:

```
start_lat = 45
lat_minutes = [59.9955, 59.9963, 60.0180, 60.0230, 60.0050, 59.6500]
```

Executing:

```
for offset in lat_minutes]:
    print (offset, formDegrees(start_lat, offset))
```

yields:

```
59.9955 45.999925
59.9963 45.99993833333333
60.018 46.0003
60.023 46.00038333333333
60.005 46.000083333333336
59.65 45.994166666666665
```

Comment: If you down grade an answer, please have the courtesy to explain why.